# Write angular2 tests and changing the mock return values - make it DRY?

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine, angular2-testing

I'm writing some tests for a service and I'm altering the response from mock functions to test various cases. At the moment, every time I want to change the response of a mock, I need to reset the TestBed and configure the testing module again, injecting my new Mocks as dependencies.

I feel like there must be a DRYer way to write this spec, but I can't figure it out. Does anyone have any ideas?

(I understand that I could write tests for this service as a standard ES6 class, but I get the same scenario with my components and services that use the Http response mocking stuff from angular.)

Here is my spec file:

```
import { TestBed, inject } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { UserService, RestService } from '../index';
import { User } from '../../../models/index';


let getUserSpy = jasmine.createSpy('getUser');
let upsertUserSpy = jasmine.createSpy('upsertUser');


// NOTE that initally, the MockRestService throws errors for all responses
class MockRestService {
  getUser = getUserSpy.and.returnValue(Observable.throw('no thanks'));
  upsertUser = upsertUserSpy.and.returnValue(Observable.throw('no thanks'));
}


describe('User service - ', () => {

  let service;

  /**
   * First TestBed configuration
   */
  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      providers: [
        UserService,
        {
          provide: RestService,
          useClass: MockRestService,
        }
      ]
    });
  });

  beforeEach(inject([UserService], (user: UserService) => {
    service = user;
  }));

  /* ... tests ... */

  describe('getUser/ upsertUser succeeds with INVALID user - ', () => {

    /**
     * Altering mock
     */
    class MockRestService {
      getUser = getUserSpy.and.returnValue(Observable.of({json: () => {
        return {name: 'dave'};
      }}));
      upsertUser = upsertUserSpy.and.returnValue(Observable.of({json: () => {}}));
    }

    /**
     * Reset and reconfigure TestBed. Lots of repetition!
     */
    beforeEach(() => {
      TestBed.resetTestingModule();
    });

    beforeEach(() => {
      TestBed.configureTestingModule({
        providers: [
          UserService,
          {
            provide: RestService,
            useClass: MockRestService,
          }
        ]
      });
    });

    beforeEach(inject([UserService], (user: UserService) => {
      service = user;
    }));

    /* ... tests ... */

  });

  describe('getUser/upsertUser succeeds with valid user', () => {
    const validResponse = {
      json: () => {
        return {
          firstName: 'dave',
          lastName: 'jones',
          email: 'dave@gmail.com'
        };
      }
    };

    /**
     * Altering mock
     */
    class MockRestService {
      getUser = getUserSpy.and.returnValue(Observable.of(validResponse));
      upsertUser = upsertUserSpy.and.returnValue(Observable.of(validResponse));
    }

    /**
     * Reset and reconfigure testbed. Lots of repetition!
     */
    beforeEach(() => {
      TestBed.resetTestingModule();
    });

    beforeEach(() => {
      TestBed.configureTestingModule({
        providers: [
          UserService,
          {
            provide: RestService,
            useClass: MockRestService,
          }
        ]
      });
    });

    beforeEach(inject([UserService], (user: UserService) => {
      service = user;
    }));

    /* ... tests ... */

  });

});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It could be some variation of

```
function setupUserTestbed() {
    beforeEach(() => {
      TestBed.configureTestingModule({...});
    });

    afterEach(() => {
      TestBed.resetTestingModule();
    });
 }

...
setupUserTestbed();
...
setupUserTestbed();
```

But the purpose of `describe` blocks (besides grouping the specs in test report) is to arrange `before*` and `after*` blocks in a way they are most efficient.

If top-level `describe` block has `beforeEach` block, you can be sure that it affects the specs in nested `describe` blocks. If `describe` blocks are siblings, common behaviour should be moved to top-level `describe`. If there's no top-level `describe` for sibling `describe` blocks, it should be created.

In posted code top-level `describe('User service - ', () => { ... })` already has `beforeEach` blocks with `TestBed.configureTestingModule`, `TestBed.resetTestingModule` (it should be performed in `afterEach`) and `inject`. There's no need to duplicate them in nested `describe` blocks.

The recipe for `MockRestService` class is the same as for any mock that alternates between specs. It should be a `let`/`var` variable:

```
describe(...
  let MockRestService = class MockRestService { ... };

  beforeEach(() => { Testbed... });

  describe(...
    MockRestService = class MockRestService { ... };

    beforeEach(inject(...));
```

There can be a lot of variations of this pattern. The class itself may be constant, but `getUser` and `upsertUser` properties may alternate:

```
let getUserSpy;
let upsertUserSpy;

class MockRestService {
  getUser = getUserSpy;
  ...
}

describe(...

  beforeEach(() => { Testbed... });

  beforeEach(() => {
    getUserSpy = jasmine.createSpy().and.returnValue(...);
    ...
  });

  describe(...
    beforeEach(() => {
      getUserSpy = jasmine.createSpy().and.returnValue(...);
      ...
    });

    beforeEach(inject(...));
```

This also solves an important issue, because spies should be fresh in each spec, i.e. be defined in `beforeEach`. `getUserSpy` and `upsertUserSpy` can be re-assigned after `Testbed` configuration but before `inject` (this is where `MockRestService` class is likely instantiated).

Comment: Thanks, I have moved my `resetTestingModule` function into an `afterEach` block in the top level describe. However, when I remove the duplicate `beforeEach` blocks from my nested `describe`s, my modified mock class `MockRestService`, which is defined in the nested `describe`, does not get injected. Have I missed your point?

Comment: I think the problem is that you can only configure the test bed once without resetting it. So If I have `configureTestBed` in the outer `describe`, I cannot call it again in a nested `describe` without resetting it first.

Comment: If the code in `beforeEach` blocks is totally duplicated, they shouldn't be repeated (this results in double bootstrapping). The pattern for `MockRestService` class is the same as for any mock variable that should be changed between specs. Either the class or its internals (getUserSpy, ...) should be re-assigned in nested `describe`s. I've updated the answer to explain this.

Comment: Ah I understand. I wasn't confident defining a class with a let, but now I know I can. Thank you!